# OutOfMemoryError when redploying my app

Tags: java, tomcat, jetty, out-of-memory

I am developing a webapp that has a plugin-loading-mechanism. The plugins are in separate jar-files and loaded with separate `URLClassLoader`s for each file. When I redeploy my app several times, I get an `OutOfMemoryError` sometime.

I have read that this is because the `URLClassLoader`s can not be garbage collected because references to classes loaded by them still exist.

How can I release this references when the app is redeployed?

The app runs on Jetty in development and on Tomcat in production. Tomcat also informs me about this memory leaks.

Comment: Instead of using something you rolled yourself, you might consider using OSGi to manage the plugins / bundles for you. Its an investment to learn how to apply it, but in the end it will pay off to use proven technology that you do not need to maintain yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the code of your plugin-loading-mechanism located? Is it in a jar  file in TOMCAT_HOME/lib or in your WAR archive?

If all your classes are within your WAR archive the leak is certainly related to the behavior of tomcats class loading mechanism.

Tomcat creates a new instance of a WebappClassLoader each time you (re)deploy an app. Each WebappClassLoader instance should be eligible for garbage collection after the corresponding app was stopped or redeployed. In case of a typical memory leak the WebappClassLoaders cannot be garbage collected, because of a strong reference to the WebappClassLoader that is still existing. In order to fix such a leak you must remove the strong reference manually.

You could follow this simple steps in order to find the leak:

- Start your server and deploy your app
- Undeploy your app (using tomcat manager)
- Create a heap dump and open it with Eclipse MAT
- Find the reference paths from your WebappClassLoader to the GC roots (exclude weak references and soft references!)
- Now you should see the strong reference that prevents the WebappClassLoader from being garbage collected.

For further information post a screenshot from the eclipse MAT here.

Answer (score -1):

There is a known issue with Tomcat 6 and threadlocals which causes memory leak, this should be fixed in Tomcat 7's memory protection feature.

see: 
http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection#customThreadLocal

Comment: The problem is not with Tomcat but with typical problematic patterns of deployed app. But Tomcat 7 even tries to work around poorly behaving apps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a ServletContextListener to release references when a web application is undeployed.

If you still see PermGen errors then you have a memory leak you need to fix. From experience, this is most likely to be in your web application or a library it is using. It is also possible, but unlikely, that you have found a memory leak in Tomcat.

The short version for tracking down the memory leak is:

```
Start Tomcat
Undeploy and redeploy the problematic application once
Use a profiler to examine the heap
Look for an instances of the WebappClassLoader
Find the one that is strongly held but has an attribute of started = false
Trace the GC roots for that instance of the WebappClassLoader
That will point to your memory leak
```

Finding the root cause of the memory leak might be a little harder.

For a fuller explanation of how to track down this sort of memory leak and what might cause them see this presentation: http://people.apache.org/~markt/presentations/2010-08-05-Memory-Leaks-JavaOne-60mins.pdf

Comment: I am using Eclipse MAT now to profile the heap. I listed all `WebappClassLoader`s using Java Basics -> Class Loader Explorer. I found 2 loaders that belong to my app, but they don't have the attribute `started`. I am using Tomcat 8.

Comment: Ah. That will be my fault for doing some refactoring to clean up the Tomcat 8 code. You need to look at the value of the state attribute. The class loader(s) you want will have a state of something other that STARTED.